# how to check if a scheduled thread has finished the task?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a task that executes every 20 seconds . But the problem is that the task can make a delay so that will cause an interruption.

```
package client;

import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;

import java.util.Date;

public class Bootstrap
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    addThreadsToPool();
    ServiceTest service1 = new ServiceTest(); 
  }

  public static void addThreadsToPool()
  {
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor eventPool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);

    eventPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Updater(), 2, 20, SECONDS);

    try {
      Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
    }
  }
}
```

in this example , class Updater executes every 20 seconds , the problem is if updater 's execution takes a period of time more than 20 seconds . 
So how to make Updater finishes ites task before the next scheduled execution?

Comment: If you want to _cancel_ `Updater` if it hasn't completed you can do so by using the `Future` returned by `scheduleAtFixedRate` and making `Updater` sensitive to cancellation (by paying attention to the interrupted state of the current thread).

Comment: would you explain more the Future  part , if the updater  hasnot completed the task I would cancel updater and allocate more time  to execute this task by multiplying the time by a factor ?

Comment: Are you trying to make sure that 2 `Updater` jobs don't run at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way but to code the Updater so that it completes in less than 20 seconds. In a strict sense this is impossible because a thread may be scheduled off the CPU, a long GC pause can happen, etc. If you run a loop inside the task, it could periodically check the time and abort if it hit the deadline.